# How to connect Elasticsearch with Trino/Presto and Superset

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, presto, trino

I need to connect a remote ES application to my local Trino and Superset application.

This is the /docker-compose.yml file that is running my local Trino and Superset application:

```yaml
x-superset-image: &superset-image docker-repo.xxxx.com/superset
x-superset-user: &superset-user root
x-superset-depends-on: &superset-depends-on
  - superset-db
  - superset-trino

x-trino-image: &trino-image docker-repo.xxxx.com/trino

version: '3.7'
services:
  superset-db:
    env_file: ./superset/.env
    image: postgres:14
    container_name: superset-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  superset-worker:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset-worker
    command: ["/app/bootstrap.sh", "worker"]
    env_file: ./superset/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    healthcheck:
      disable: true

  superset-worker-beat:
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset-worker-beat
    command: ["/app/bootstrap.sh", "beat"]
    env_file: ./superset/.env
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on
    healthcheck:
      disable: true

  superset-app:
    env_file: ./superset/.env
    build: ./superset
    image: *superset-image
    container_name: superset-app
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    user: *superset-user
    depends_on: *superset-depends-on

  superset-trino:
    build: ./trino
    image: *trino-image
    container_name: superset-trino
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

This is my /superset/Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/superset

USER root

RUN pip install psycopg2 --no-cache-dir \
    pip install elasticsearch-dbapi --no-cache-dir \
    pip install trino --no-cache-dir

RUN mkdir /home/superset
RUN chown superset:superset /app
RUN chown superset:superset /home/superset

COPY --chown=superset:superset init.sh /app/init.sh
COPY --chown=superset:superset bootstrap.sh /app/bootstrap.sh

USER superset
```

This is my /trino/etc/catalog/elasticsearch.properties ([reference](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/elasticsearch.html#connector-elasticsearch--page-root)):

```
connector.name=elasticsearch
elasticsearch.host=https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
elasticsearch.port=my_port
elasticsearch.default-schema-name=default
elasticsearch.ignore-publish-address=true
elasticsearch.security=password
elasticsearch.auth.user=my_user
elasticsearch.auth.password=my_password
```

This is how I run it:

```
docker compose up
docker exec -it superset-app ./init.sh
```

Then I go to the Superset UI (localhost:8080) and:

1. Click on Settings
2. Click on Database Connections
3. Add a Trino connection: elasticsearch, trino://trino@superset-trino/elasticsearch
4. Click on SQL Lab, select elasticsearch as DATABASE, default as SCHEMA

This is the error I'm getting:

```
2023-07-03T21:50:59.940Z ERROR stage-scheduler io.trino.execution.scheduler.PipelinedQueryScheduler Failure in distributed stage for query 20230703_215059_00020_4icke
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Error listing table columns for catalog elasticsearch: https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
...
Caused by: io.trino.spi.TrinoException: https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
...
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
...
io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Error listing table columns for catalog elasticsearch: https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx
...
```

If I use `xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx` as host instead of `https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx` I get:

```
...
superset-trino        | io.trino.spi.TrinoException: Connection is closed
...
```

The error suggests I'm hitting an "Unknownhost" as if `https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx` was not known. However, when I try:

```
curl -k -u my_user:my_password https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx:my_port
```

I actually get something back, so it suggests that `https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx:my_port` is actually a known host.

If I can make a curl to `https://xx-xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxx:my_port`, why can't Trino connect to it?